# Cannot find `SignalR` in `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` in .NET Core 2.2?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, signalr

I'm not so sure why this can be a problem, I've just revised some documentation about `SignalR` in ASP.NET Core and it seems to mean that I don't have to install any additional package (already have `Microsoft.AspNetCore.All` and `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` referenced after creating a new ASP.NET Core project (version 2.2).

I've even tried Googling and found this blog post: https://wakeupandcode.com/real-time-asp-net-core-web-apps-with-signalr/#dep

It was written on Dec 23 2018, and the author does confirm that we don't need to install any additional package.

Well so it's really playing on me, making me have a feeling of being stupid, not so sure why I cannot use `SignalR` in my project (I'm not intending to install any additional package, which I think should work for me), just wonder why it's not already available. The following code does not compile:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;
```

It reports that `SignalR` does not exist in the namespace `Microsoft.AspNetCore` right in the project that has `Microsoft.AspNetCore.All` and `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App`.

Actually I cannot find the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR` when expanding the references tree.
The documentation says nothing about where to import the module (which means it should already be available). As I said the project targets `.NET Core 2.2`. Could you explain to me something could be wrong here?

PS: My project is a Web API (not MVC) project.

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
  <Folder Include="wwwroot\" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="Autofac" Version="4.9.4" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.0.9" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting" Version="2.2.0" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: It's definitely part of the meta package. I assume you've tried removing the packages directory and then running `dotnet restore`

Comment: @AluanHaddad I'm not so sure about what you meant, I've done nothing special to my newly created project. I don't use `dotnet` CLI at all, I prefer to clicking buttons on Visual Studio

Comment: Try it out. The meta package explicitly lists SignalR so it should be available [See here under dependencies](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.All/2.2.7).

Comment: @AluanHaddad yes it's right there, but somehow it's missing in my project. As I said I've tried expanding the references tree and really the `SignalR` is not listed :( all are just default scaffolded.

Comment: my `Microsoft.AspNetCore.All` version is `2.0.9` which actually does not include `SignalR`. I don't understand why creating a new project does not add a newer version for it.

Comment: Could you post your .csproj file here? It seems you target an old version of the framework which does not include SignalR (which was added in asp.net core 2.1).

Comment: @Sergiy you can see my update at the end, the added version for `Microsoft.AspNetCore.All` is `2.0.9` although the targeted .NET Core is `2.2`

Comment: @Hopeless So, I guess the problem is solved? You just need to remove that version number from your meta-package reference and .net core automatically takes the latest one for targeting framework version. Like:
`<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" />`

Comment: @Sergiy yes, I just needed to update it to the higher version which is required at least 2.1.0 to use SignalR. I've doubted that the project was targeted as 2.0 first then retargeting it to 2.2 does not upgrade the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.All`

Answer (score 0):

Usually, project templates have outdated libraries. Use the NuGet package manager to update references to recent versions and try again. It should help.

Comment: this is just correct up to some point, if you target the correct framework initially, all minimal versions of packages should be added. In my case there was a high chance that I targeted it as `2.0` first, then re-targeted it to `2.2`. This however does not upgrade the packages automatically (maybe a bug?)

Comment: Rather missing feature than a bug. Yesterday I've tried one of the MS online Azure tutorials using the sandbox. I was following instructions and got an error. As it occurs sandbox was in core 2.2 but all instructions force me to install the newest versions of all libs which were 3.0. I've observed tendency to update templates more recently than before.